# Issue with ajax Add to Cart button

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, ajax, shopping-cart

I want to add add to cart button without reloading the page.

For this I found this [Excellence](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/04/magento-add-product-to-cart-ajax/) extension. But I have a problem when I add the product in cart, my minicart from top page is not updating. I found this in the code:

```
success: function(data){
    jQuery('#ajax_loader').hide();
    //alert(data.status + ": " + data.message);
    if(jQuery('.block-cart')){
        jQuery('.block-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
    }
    if(jQuery('.header .links')){
        jQuery('.header .links').replaceWith(data.toplink);
    }
}
```

and my HTML output is look like this:

```
<div class="top-cart-contain">
    <div class="mini-cart">
        <div class="basket dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
            <a href="http://example.com/checkout/cart/">
                <div class="cart-box">
                    <span class="title">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i>
                        My Cart:
                        <span>1 prekės</span>
                        Price:
                        <span class="price">13,74 €</span>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make this extension to update my top cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery does not find your cart block because the class `.block-cart` is not the right one in your case. I suggest you replace:

```
if(jQuery('.block-cart')){
    jQuery('.block-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
}
```

With:

```
if(jQuery('.mini-cart')){
    jQuery('.mini-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, but if I change this in my top cart is blank now

Comment: @RobertD check what's the content of `data.sidebar` ?

Comment: I talk about minicart from top, that minicart,  and in controller of this extension I have this:

                    $toplink = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();
                    $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar');

Comment: @RobertD yeah what do you get in the `data` response ?

Comment: what I need to do to see this data response?

Comment: @RobertD add `alert(data)` to your code. Also try with `alert(data.sidebar)`

Comment: in the view.phtml? on that script? anyway I think now after I press add to cart button and after updating instead minicart I see the left cart sidebar

Comment: @RobertD I just tried on your website and it works fine for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45415/discussion-between-robertd-and-raphael-at-digital-pianism).